# How to decide what libraries to include when adding firebase sdk to ios (flutter) project?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter

I have recently opened up a flutter/firebase project that I haven't worked on in about 6 months.

Being slightly out of date now, it would no longer build... and so I wasted no time completely hosing the project in my attempts to resolve the error messages.

So now I'm using my tried and true method: Create a new flutter project, add all the necessary dependencies, make sure it builds, then cut and paste the dart code from the old project.

Anyway, since this project uses firebase, I'm at the stage where I'm adding the app to the firebase console.

I've successfully added GoogleService-Info.plist to the ios component of the app, but I'm stuck on the next step (3) "Add Firebase SDK":

[image]

When adding "firebase-ios-sdk" to the project in XCode, it is suggested (as you can see above) that I "Choose the firebase libraries that [I] want to use."

There are 28 libraries, many with similar names and none of which with any "more info" available.

[image]

How exactly is a person supposed to make this choice?
Is there any harm in simply selecting all of them?  Will this lead to a bloated app, or will unused libraries be optimized out?

Comment: if you work with flutter you shouldn't use from swift package manager config and SDK, you must use add the following dependencies to you flutter pubspec.yaml file:(firebase_core: ^1.10.0
  firebase_analytics: ^8.3.4
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.3.0
  firebase_messaging: ^11.1.0), in picture you shared you see the SPM or COCOAPOD config that doesn't use in flutter.

Comment: see the installation in this link https://pub.dev/packages?q=firebase

Comment: in the first picture you have shared you can see Add or installation SDK with 5 method (SPM, POD, ZIP, UNITY, C++)